# Assigning a default variable in URL using PHP

Tags: php, variables

I'm new to this forum. I've been browsing the internet for several hours but i couldn't find anything so i hope you guys can help me.
I'm building a website with an introductory text in several languages. I've used this: http://www.webgeekly.com/tutorials/jquery/how-to-make-your-site-multilingual-using-xml-and-jquery/
what it does is change content inside divs from an external xml web. 
It then retrieves the language from the url with typical PHP (which i don't have much idea of): using something like ?lang='eng'
The thing is i would like the variable    lang    to be set to 'eng' by default. 
It isn't and the text won't load.

Is there a way to assign it in the url or anywhere else?
Thank you very much

Comment: can you adjust the logic so if no language is defined in the url it assumes english?

Answer (score 2):

Update the jquery line:

```
var language = '<?php echo $sLanguage; ?>';
```

to read

```
var language = '<?php echo ((isset($_GET['lang']))?$_GET['lang']:'english') ?>';
```

that way if they append ?lang=italian, it will use that, and if not assume english.

Comment: my assumption is poster, doesn't even know what a PHP file is. Might not help at all.

Comment: Yes, and looking at the provided link I don't even see PHP being used..  jQuery is loading the xml directly, so I will update my answer to use jquery instead

Comment: NOTE!  If this value ('lang') is shown anywhere on the page, and not solely passed as an argument to the xml, you would want to filter the value for malicious input.   http://php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php

Answer (score 0):

Could you not use an if statement, for example:

```
    if (isset($_GET['lang'])) {
    $lang = $_GET["lang"];
    // language content goes here
    } else {
    $lang = "eng";
    // english content goes here
    }
```

I am fairly new to php too but I think this would work.

Comment: Mike that was my previous answer, but as Jakub pointed out he does not know php, nor does the script he borrowed use a php script other than a simple echo statement.  It is one of the worst tutorials I have seen on the web.

Answer (score 0):

On server side you can do this very short, like that:

```
$lang = isset($_REQUEST['lang']) ? $_REQUEST['lang'] : 'eng';
```

To **autodetect** what language your visitor is probably been using, try this (and change the language of your browser):

```
$browserLang = explode(',', $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']);
$lang = isset($_REQUEST['lang']) ? $_REQUEST['lang'] : $browserLang[0];
```

Comment: You don't want to use `$_REQUEST` as its a superglobal, be safe define for what you need, if you need `$_GET` use get...